# ibus-avro is not working everywhere on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, 22.04, google-chrome, libreoffice, ibus-avro

ibus-avro for Bangla typing in Linux is not working everywhere, i.e it's working on Firefox, but not working on Chrome. It's also not working on LibreOffice, text editor, etc.

[image: image of Firefox typing]
<sup>**Firefox**</sup>

[image: image of Chrome typing]
<sup>**Chrome**</sup>

Comment: Did you configure Avro properly? From the screenshot, it looks like some other Bangla writing engine, not Avro. Avro looks like this. https://imgur.com/a/FsCgU1n

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi: The Avro icon is not visible in the top bar on Ubuntu with GNOME.

Comment: Did you reboot the computer after configuring ibus?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson maybe the interface (https://imgur.com/a/vs5yJCr) has changed in this version (Ubuntu 22.04.1). And yes, I reboot the computer after configuring ibus.

Comment: @Noyon: No, not in that respect. GNOME integrates IBus in a way which differs from other desktop environments. I can't reproduce the issue with any of those applications you mention.